# Pattern matching Data.Sequence like lists

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, abstract-data-type, pattern-synonyms

I am using [`Data.Sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Sequence.html) instead lists for better performance.  With lists we can do the following

```
foo :: [Int] -> Int
foo [] m = m
foo (x:xs) m = ...
```

How can this be accomplished with `Data.Sequence`.  I have tried the following:

```
foo:: S.Seq Int -> Int
foo S.empty m = m
foo (x S.<: xs) m = ...
```

I think the solution involves using `S.viewl` and `S.viewr`, but cannot seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ViewPatterns` is probably the way to go here. Your code doesn't work because you need to call `viewl` or `viewr` on your `Seq` first to get something of type `ViewL` or `ViewR`. `ViewPatterns` can handle that pretty nicely:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

foo (S.viewl -> S.EmptyL)    = ... -- empty on left
foo (S.viewl -> (x S.:< xs)) = ... -- not empty on left
```

Which is equivalent to something like:

```
foo seq = case S.viewl seq of
    S.EmptyL    -> ...
    (x S.:< xs) -> ...
```

Answer (score 17):

As of GHC 7.8, you can use [pattern synonyms](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms) together with [view patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) for this purpose:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, PatternSynonyms #-}

import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq

pattern Empty   <- (Seq.viewl -> Seq.EmptyL)
pattern x :< xs <- (Seq.viewl -> x Seq.:< xs)
pattern xs :> x <- (Seq.viewr -> xs Seq.:> x)
```

As of GHC 7.10, you can also make it into a bidirectional pattern synonym, so that `Empty`, `(:<)` and `(:>)` can be used as "constructors" as well:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, PatternSynonyms #-}

import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq

pattern Empty   <- (Seq.viewl -> Seq.EmptyL)  where Empty = Seq.empty
pattern x :< xs <- (Seq.viewl -> x Seq.:< xs) where (:<)  = (Seq.<|) 
pattern xs :> x <- (Seq.viewr -> xs Seq.:> x) where (:>)  = (Seq.|>)
```

Comment: Excellent, I had no idea this made it into 7.10. Why is the [GHC ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8581) still open for it though?

Comment: @AndrásKovács: erhmm... I've left it open because the matcher vs builder type context issues in that ticket haven't been completely addressed yet.

Comment: Note, [per the wiki](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/pattern-synonyms/complete-sigs), that "[t]he exhaustiveness checker currently chokes on pattern synonyms." We can reassure the compiler that our patterns are exhaustive using the [COMPLETE pragma](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/pattern-synonyms/complete-sigs#syntax). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74526666/12162258).